# Why doesn't my Swift struct property appear in framework?

Tags: swift, frameworks

I have declared a Swift struct in a framework, like so:

```
public struct Thing {
  var myProperty: String
}
```

I can access this in the framework tests without issue.

However, when I link to this framework in an iOS app only this appears in the header:

```
public struct Thing {
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default access level is `internal`.  You must mark your property as `public` if you want it to show up outside the module.

```
public struct Thing {
    public var myProperty: String
}
```